# Is $f_a$ convex function for various value of $a$?

Tags: convex-analysis

> $f_{a}:[a,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $a\leq 0$
>
> $$f_{a}(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } x=0 \\   0& \text{ if } x \neq 0
>    \end{cases}$$ A) $f_{a}$ is convex for all $a\leq 0$
>
> B) $f_{a}$ is not convex for any $a\leq 0$
>
> C) $f_{a}$ is a convex function  for all $a< 0$ and not convex for $a = 0$
>
> D) $f_{a}$ is not convex function  for any$a< 0$ and  convex for $a =0$

[image]

This is what the ploted graph looks like right?

How do we know id it's convex?

Comment: what does $\neq > $ and $= > $ mean? do they mean $\neq $ and $ \geq$ respectively?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh  Now go ahead..

Comment: what have you tried? are there some values for $a$ where you already have a solution?

Comment: Well,it's linear everywhere except at a=0 it is a single point.  I don't know what conclusion we can draw from this?

Comment: In the definition of  $f_a$, @MAthsjunky you said $a\leq 0$, in statement (C),(D) you have $a\geq 0$, $a=0$ would be better.

Comment: Yes, i fixed it. That was the original question, someone edited it.

Comment: Can you state the solution ,please?

Comment: what happens if you apply the definition of convexity?

Comment: @MAthsjunky I think you need to use Jensen's inequality